# Why the header of datatable misaligned with the content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a datatable that th header misaligned with the content. Please help me to adjust the header and content so that parallel. Because it look

[image: ]([![picture]

```html
<div style="margin-top:10px; padding: 10px;">
  <table id="example" class="table display nowrap table-bordered table-striped" style="width:100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test34567</th>
        <th>Test890</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>D</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollX: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Issues like that are normally caused by CSS. `scrollX` by itself works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vj2ce2pe/

Comment: issue with the `css`. may be some of these class`display nowrap table-bordered table-striped` have property display block

Answer (score 0):

I know its been a while but the solution still might help others as I had the similar issue recently,

This scenario is happening because of the scrollX. You can set the scrollX to false or update the CSS to adjust the header width to 100%. This can be done inside the JS,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
    scrollX: true
  });

  //Newly added lines
  $(".dataTables_scrollHeadInner").css( "width", "100%" );
  $(".dataTables_scrollHeadInner table").css( "width", "100%" );

});
```

This solution is inspired by the [answer](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/153217/#Comment_153217) posted in the datatable discussion forum